# NSFetchedResultsController not inserting objects into UITableView correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I am using a UITableView with a NSFetchedResultsController. The fetch has some predicates and it all works fine. All objects have an index by which they should be sorted.
When I insert an object this index gets set correctly, but sometimes the object appears at a wrong index path. But, when I leave the view controller and come back the order is correct. I tried refreshing the table view in `controllerDidChangeContent:` with no effect.

This is my fetch request:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"NoteContent" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"note IN %@", self.container.notes];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"note.creation.description" ascending:NO];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"index" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor, sortDescriptor2];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

I'm thankful for any idea on what the problem could be.

Comment: Most likely place for the problem to be occurring is in the delegate methods, try adding those as well.

Comment: Create above method as globally and call this method whenever you have do add,edit and delete methods along with separated methods. then you will get exact solution.

Comment: Also add the code where you insert new objects and set the `index`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the insertion part is totally fine, but I did not update the indices when deleting, which resulted in index gaps.